# complexity of factoring multivariate polynomials over Fn

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, reference-request, polynomials

recently multivariate polynomial factoring has been [related](http://eccc.hpi-web.de/report/2014/001/) to [Polynomial Identity Testing / PIT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartz%E2%80%93Zippel_lemma#Comparison_of_two_polynomials) (by Kopparty, Saraf, Shpilka).

> where is the complexity of factoring multivariate polynomials over [finite fields](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_field) analyzed/ surveyed, in particular for **F<sub>2</sub>**?

(eg is there a complete problem related to that, or does KSS result relate to factorization over finite fields etc?)

Comment: A quick web search reveals many sources, and there are also several monographs I can think of that answer your question. Have you looked at these sources?

Comment: I think they reduce factoring to PIT. Is there a reverse connection?